# How to remove Ubuntu installed alongside another version of Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I successfully installed desktop 13.04 beside 12.04. Now that I have confirmed that 13.04 works and have retrieved old data files, how do I remove 12.04 to regain file space?

Answer (score 0):

GParted should do the trick (`sudo apt-get install gparted`). Delete the partition that has 12.04 on it, along with 12.04's swap partition (if applicable), resize 13.04's partition to fill the whole disk.